# java font format exception on osx with java 4 update

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, fonts, jruby

I'm getting a

> java.awt.FontFormatException:
>   Unrecognised Font Format

error, and I believe this has been happening only since performing the 10.5 java 4 update, though I can't verify that to be exact.  My java version after the update is 1.5.0_19

I'm using jruby in rails to generate a font with the following code:

```
font = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font::TRUETYPE_FONT, java.io.FileInputStream.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/Arial.ttf"))
```

The Arial.ttf is taken from my OSX fonts folder and it is obviously a TTF, so what is wrong?

Has anyone experienced any odd font issues after upgrading java?  I don't know if I have to update jruby after updating java, but I can't imagine that's the case.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. Apparently its a problem with user permissions. 
In my case the problem occurred when starting up my weblogic server. I was running Weblogic as root, but my font file was owned by a system user. Changing the permissions of the file did not solve my problem, but changing the ownership of Weblogic itself did. So if I run my server with the same user that owns the font file, the problem magically disappeared.

I guess the update solved some security or ownership issues that introduced a new problem. Hope the solution to my problem helps you find the cause of yours.

good luck

Siets

Comment: that's interesting.  I'm glad at least that I'm not alone. Unfortunately for me, I am already running my jruby rails app server as the user that owns the TTF file :(

Comment: scratch that, Completely forgot I'm running jruby as sudo to access rdebug.  Running it normally fixed the problem.  Good find!